# pack bytes array with strange alignment requirements

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, arrays, gpu

Suppose you have 32 threads and 32 pieces of data for each thread to operate on independently, e.g.

```
struct data
{
  unsigned short int N;
  char *features;  //array length N
  uint *values;  //array length N
};

data alldata[32];
```

Suppose that the shared memory for these threads is "partitioned" into 32 "banks", where each bank is 4 bytes wide.  **Each thread can read from its corresponding "bank" in parallel, but if threads try to access the same bank simlutaneously, the read operation serializes.**

```
bank      |        0        |         1       |         2        |   .....
bytes     |  0   1   2   3  |  4   5  6   7   |  8   9   10  11  |  ....
bytes     | 128 129 130 131 | 132 133 134 135 | 136 137 138 139  |  ...
...............
...............
threads   |       0         |         1       |         2        |   .....
```

(This bizarre situation is called GPU computing).

Thus, for maximum parallelization:
(in terms of the picture above) the member variables of alldata[0] must only be written to the bytes in the first column.  The member of variables of alldata[1] to the second column, etc.  Equivalently,

In other words, I must write the contents of `alldata[32]` into one dynamic array, where the member variables of `alldata[j]` are written in 4-byte intervals once every `32*4` bytes.  Then, when I copy this dynamic array into the shared memory for the threads, it will be properly aligned for the banks.

**Question:**
Does anybody know of any kind of package that will write variables to a byte array with proper spacing, as discussed above (once every `32*4` bytes)  ?

This is a desperation question...

Comment: So, does this all translate to "How do I align structs to 128 byte"?

Comment: @PlasmaHH No, because you need to alternate. e.g.  write first four bytes of `alldata[0]` , then write first four bytes of `alldata[1]`, then first four bytes of `alldata[2]`, ....., the second four bytes of `alldata[0]`, then second four bytes of `alldata[1]`,.....

Comment: What data type is `alldata[32]`?

Comment: @wallyk   Oops, thank you.  I corrected the typo.